# Create a pairwise dataframe that matches up more than two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I am currently using the following code to match up every value in one dataframe column to every value in another dataframes column:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['CompanyA'], df2['CompanyB']), columns=["CompanyA","CompanyB"]) 

new_df_address1 = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['Address1A'], df2['Address1B']), columns=["Address1A","Address1B"]) 

new_df_postcode = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['PostcodeA'], df2['PostcodeB']), columns=["PostcodeA","PostcodeB"]) 

(and a few more pairs with the same code)
```

What I would like to do is on the initial pairing of CompanyA to CompanyB is also carry through the Address1A, Address 1B, PostcodeA, PostcodeB etc. to create one dataframe containing all the information.

I would like to avoid calculating each seperately and appending them to one another in case there is some mix up in the order between calculations.

Thanks!

EDIT: Sample of Data

```
df1:
CompanyA      Address1A        Address2A   PostcodeA ...
Trees inc.    1 Hill Street    London      FH5 8YB
```

df2:

```
CompanyB      Address1B        Address2B   PostcodeB ...
Boxes inc.    4 High Street    York        AK5 FJ6
Hats inc.     17 River Lane    Bolton      YT5 9NB
```

paired df:

```
CompanyA      Address1A        Address2A   PostcodeA  CompanyB      Address1B        Address2B   PostcodeB ...
Trees inc.    1 Hill Street    London      FH5 8YB    Boxes inc.    4 High Street    York        AK5 FJ6
Trees inc.    1 Hill Street    London      FH5 8YB    Hats inc.     17 River Lane    Bolton      YT5 9NB 
etc
```

The desired output is every row in df1 mapped to every row in df2.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add in your data? (or a sample of it)

Comment: Just added to main text!

Comment: Not quite as that would just contatenate the two dataframes 1 to 1. I would like every row in df1 paired with every row in df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to do a cartesian product of your dataframes on your right keys only.

```
df = pd.merge(df1.assign(key="var1"), df2.assign(key="var1"), on="key", how="right").drop(
    "key", 1
)

print(df)

     CompanyA      Address1A Address2A PostcodeA    CompanyB      Address1B  \
0  Trees inc.  1 Hill Street    London   FH5 8YB  Boxes inc.  4 High Street   
1  Trees inc.  1 Hill Street    London   FH5 8YB   Hats inc.  17 River Lane   

  Address2B PostcodeB  
0      York   AK5 FJ6  
1    Bolton   YT5 9NB
```

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was after!